# What should I do to make the new University appeared in the Webometrics ranking?

Tags: ranking

What should I do to make a new University appear in the Webometrics ranking?

http://www.webometrics.info

Are scientific publications by researchers affiliated with this University (additionally assumes quoted) sufficient?

We assume that the University has a website.

Theoretical question.

Comment: What do you find out at that site?

Comment: @GEdgar it looks rather sketchy